# Why does customElements.upgrade appear to not upgrade this custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

I have a situation similar to the example below: from a `template` element, I clone a node tree containing custom elements. One custom element is passed data during initialization, represented here by the line `infobox.setData(getData())`. The function I use to pass the data (`setData`) is added by my custom class, so I make sure the custom element is upgraded before calling it, by passing the node tree to `customElements.upgrade`. (I have also tried passing `infobox` itself.)

Unfortunately, when I try running my code or the example below I receive the error `infobox.setData is not a function`. I have confirmed `infobox instanceof InfoBox` is false and the element has no custom properties or methods prior to being connected to the document, so it seems `customElements.upgrade` is not upgrading the elements in the tree. What might be preventing it from doing so?

```js
document.getElementById('addWidgetErr').onclick = addWidgetErr
document.getElementById('addWidgetWorkaround').onclick = addWidgetWorkaround

class InfoBox extends HTMLElement {
  _data = ""

  connectedCallback() {
    this.render()
  }

  setData(val) {
    this._data = val
    this.render()
  }

  render() {
    if (!this?.isConnected) {
      return
    }

    this.replaceChildren(...this._data.split(' ').map(datum => {
      const el = document.createElement('span')
      el.innerText = datum
      return el
    }))
  }
}
customElements.define('info-box', InfoBox)

function addWidgetErr() {
  const widget = document.getElementById('widgetTemplate').content.cloneNode(true)
  const infobox = widget.querySelector('info-box')

  // From my understanding, this should convert all unknown elements in `widget`
  //   into custom elements.
  customElements.upgrade(widget)

  console.assert(!(infobox instanceof InfoBox))
  console.assert(!('setData' in infobox))
  // TypeError: infobox.setData is not a function
  infobox.setData(getData())

  document.getElementById('container').append(widget)
}

function addWidgetWorkaround() {
  const widget = document.getElementById('widgetTemplate').content.cloneNode(true)
  const infobox = widget.querySelector('info-box')

  document.getElementById('container').append(widget)

  // works because infobox has been upgraded after being added to the document
  infobox.setData(getData())
}

function getData() {
  return ('lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit proin at ' +
    'vestibulum enim vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus')
}
```

```css
#container {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 2em;
}

info-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  background: darkgrey;
}

info-box>span {
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<template id="widgetTemplate">
    <details>
        <info-box></info-box>
    </details>
</template>

<button id="addWidgetErr">Add via `upgrade`</button>
<button id="addWidgetWorkaround">Add post-hoc</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: No error when I run your code in Chromium or FireFox. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Firefox 93.0 and 95.0.2, and Chrome 96.0.4664.110.
I had wrapped `infobox.setData(getData())` in a `try` block to show how the other, post-hoc, call to `setData` worked as expected. I have modified my example to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I narrowed it down to `<template>` / `cloneNode`

Submit it here: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues
(Your credits if it is a bug, in other words *I don't have a clue* :-)

```js
class myEl extends HTMLElement {}

let el1 = document.createElement("my-el");
let el2 = Object.assign(document.createElement("template"), {
            innerHTML: "<my-el></my-el>"
          }).content.cloneNode(true).querySelector("my-el");

customElements.define("my-el", myEl);

customElements.upgrade(el1); // works as documented
customElements.upgrade(el2); // doesn't upgrade!

console.assert(el1 instanceof myEl, "element not upgraded");
console.assert(el2 instanceof myEl, "template not upgraded");
```

##### Update: submitted by OP as issue: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/946#issuecomment-1200377464

Comment: Thank you! I will wait a day to see if anyone has any further input then accept this answer and post a bug report. It seems I also need to find a proper workaround for my project.

Comment: Ah! From [#740](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/740) I gleaned a possible hack: applying `document.importNode(node, deep)` to a node that is already in the document acts just like `node.cloneNode(deep)` but with the side-effect of upgrading the cloned nodes. A few quick tests suggests this works properly on `template` contents.